# How to sort table as per the number value using Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to sort the table row value as per one column which contains some number type value using Angular.js. I am providing my code below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in clickSummary">
   <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
   <td>{{c.rest_name}}</td>
   <td>{{c.page_hit}}</td>
   <td>{{c.map_hit}}</td>
   <td>{{c.gallery_hit}}</td>
   <td>{{c.web_hit}}</td>
   <td>{{c.total}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here `clickSummary` obejct is containing some array of data.This above table output is displaying like below.

```
sl no    name    page hit   map hit     gallery hit    web hit    total

1        aaa       1             1         0             1          3

2        bbb       2             2         1              0          5

3        ccc       1             2         3              0           6

4        ddd       1             3         0              0            4

5       eee        2             4         1              2            9
```

I need to sort as per `total` column value means it should come in descending order(`9,6,5,4,3`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By `orderBy` filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in clickSummary | orderBy:['-total','+rest_name'] ">
```

Here is a live <kbd>**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/Hp4W7/32/)**</kbd>

[Angular orderBy Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy#usage):

> Orders a specified array by the expression predicate. It is ordered alphabetically for strings and numerically for numbers. Note: if you notice numbers are not being sorted as expected, make sure they are actually being saved as numbers and not strings. Array-like values (e.g. NodeLists, jQuery objects, TypedArrays, Strings, etc) are also supported.

Comment: Ok,its working.But suppose one `total` value lets say `9` came multiple time can we again sort it as per name alphabetical order ?

Comment: try `c in clickSummary | orderBy:['-total','+name']`

Comment: its `rest_name` instead of `name`.Please make this correct.

Comment: Now its perfect.Let me to accept this answer.Thanks again.

Comment: Using `orderBy` in the html causes the array to be resorted every digest cycle, which can be impact performance for views with long lists or many usages. If the array is static after sorting, it's best to use `orderBy`  in the controller when the array is loaded. Angular2 has no `orderBy` feature for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

you can use angularJS default filters using `|` character

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in clickSummary | orderBy:'-total'">
   <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
   <td>{{c.rest_name}}</td>
   <td>{{c.page_hit}}</td>
   <td>{{c.map_hit}}</td>
   <td>{{c.gallery_hit}}</td>
   <td>{{c.web_hit}}</td>
   <td>{{c.total}}</td>
</tr>
```

if you want to sort for multiple items you can creare an array, for example total and name:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in clickSummary | orderBy:['-total','name']">
   <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
   <td>{{c.rest_name}}</td>
   <td>{{c.page_hit}}</td>
   <td>{{c.map_hit}}</td>
   <td>{{c.gallery_hit}}</td>
   <td>{{c.web_hit}}</td>
   <td>{{c.total}}</td>
</tr>
```